# regex to exclude certain special characters

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex...I am validating it on the client-side(javascript)

accepts all characters/number and all other special charaters except 3 special characters such as '÷' , 'ç' and þ. I am just a beginner please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[^÷çþ]+$
```

Use it like this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/PZJVq/).

Comment: Thanks, Trying it now...will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @jqs: That _should_ work fine, to be the on safe side you may want to go with the Hex coded version: `^[^\xF7\xFE\xE7]+$` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/2RcHA/)

Comment: second option doesnt work...I have a fuction called addresslineValidation where I am writing the regex. Then I am calling that function on a element to which I need to apply the regex...

Comment: @jqs: `þ` works fine for me.  Is it just your code that's not working, or the demos as well?

Comment: I am looking for the first one...sorry my bad.

Comment: @jqs: Ah, i think `Þ` is a capital `þ`... maybe! Try this instead: `^[^\xF7\xDE\xE7]+$` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/2RcHA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Find the unicode number for these characters (using your debugger to cast them to an int, or using a program called charmap.exe).  The division symbol looks like F7 in hex.  Then, you can use this format for your regex:

```
\u00F7
```